# ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL: what are the valid audio formats to use?

Tags: ios, core-audio

So my question is: what are the valid audio formats to use with ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL?

I am recording in a renderCallback from RemoteIO - and have it working using these specs:

> **AudioStreamBasicDescription** :: mFormatID :: kAudioFormatLinearPCM
>
> **ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL** :: AudioFileTypeID :: kAudioFileWAVEType

But the resulting files are huge, so I want to use a compressed format. I've been searching for a few hours and plugging in various format combinations but I get errors:

```
uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: 'Couldn't create file for writing'
```

I've also seen conflicting info about what formats can and cannot be used to record. For a reality check, I tinkered with the SpeakHere example and got it working with kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC - but for the life of me, I can't those settings to work in my own project.

Any tips on using ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL to record compressed audio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this - recording to AAC directly to ExtAudioFile. Details here: [Recording to AAC from RemoteIO: data is getting written but file unplayable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113977/recording-to-aac-from-remoteio-data-is-getting-written-but-file-unplayable)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AudioFileGetGlobalInfo` (etc.) to determine what the current system supports.

When recording, just record as PCM, compress the result, dispose the PCM recording, if the system does not support the destination format you need.