# Recording to AAC from RemoteIO: data is getting written but file unplayable

Tags: ios, ios5, core-audio

I have been trying to record from a RemoteIO unit directly to AAC in a renderCallback in iOS 5 on an iPad 2. I have seen conflicting info saying it is not possible & that it is possible (in the comments [here](http://atastypixel.com/blog/easy-aac-compressed-audio-conversion-on-ios/)). My reason for wanting to do it is because recording to PCM requires so much disk space for a recording of any length - even if it is later converted to AAC.

I'm about ready to give up though. I've scraped through Google, SO, the Core Audio book and the Apple Core-Audio mailing list & forums and have reached the point where I am not getting any errors - and am recording *something* to disk but the resulting file is unplayable. This is the case with both the Simulator and on the device.

So... if anyone has experience with this, I'd really appreciate a nudge in the right direction. The setup is that the RemoteIO is playing output from AUSamplers & that is working fine.

Here is what I am doing in the code below

- Specify the `AudioStreamBasicDescription` formats for the remoteIO
  unit to `kAudioFormatLinearPCM`
- Create and specify the destination format for the `ExtAudioFileRef`
  Specify the client format by getting it from the RemoteIO unit
- Specify the renderCallback for the RemoteID unit
- In the renderCallback, write data in the
  `kAudioUnitRenderAction_PostRender` phase

As I said, I am not getting any errors, and the resulting audio file sizes show something is being written, but the file is unplayable. Perhaps I have my formats screwed up?

Anyway, this is my message in a bottle and/or "Be Here Dragons" flag to anyone else braving the dark waters of Core-Audio.

---

//The unhappy msg I get when trying to play the file:

[image]

// part of remoteIO setup

```
    // Enable IO for recording

UInt32 flag = 1;
result = AudioUnitSetProperty(ioUnit, 
                              kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, 
                              kAudioUnitScope_Input, 
                              kInputBus, // == 1
                              &flag, 
                              sizeof(flag));
if (noErr != result) {[self printErrorMessage: @"Enable IO for recording" withStatus: result]; return;}

// Describe format - - - - - - - - - -
size_t bytesPerSample = sizeof (AudioUnitSampleType);
AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat;
memset(&audioFormat, 0, sizeof(audioFormat));
audioFormat.mSampleRate   = 44100.00;
audioFormat.mFormatID     = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
audioFormat.mFormatFlags    = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
audioFormat.mBitsPerChannel   = 16;
audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket   = 2;
audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame    = 2;

result = AudioUnitSetProperty(ioUnit, 
                              kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, 
                              kAudioUnitScope_Output, 
                              kInputBus, // == 1
                              &audioFormat, 
                              sizeof(audioFormat));


result = AudioUnitSetProperty(ioUnit, 
                              kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, 
                              kAudioUnitScope_Input, 
                              kOutputBus, // == 0
                              &audioFormat, 
                              sizeof(audioFormat));
```

// Function that sets up file & rendercallback

```
 - (void)startRecordingAAC
{

OSStatus result;

NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *recordFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"audio.m4a"];

CFURLRef destinationURL = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault, 
                                                        (__bridge   CFStringRef)recordFile, 
                                                        kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, 
                                                        false);

AudioStreamBasicDescription destinationFormat;
memset(&destinationFormat, 0, sizeof(destinationFormat));
destinationFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;
destinationFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC;
UInt32 size = sizeof(destinationFormat);
result = AudioFormatGetProperty(kAudioFormatProperty_FormatInfo, 0, NULL, &size, &destinationFormat);        
if(result) printf("AudioFormatGetProperty %ld \n", result);


result = ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL(destinationURL, 
                                   kAudioFileM4AType, 
                                   &destinationFormat, 
                                   NULL, 
                                   kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile, 
                                   &extAudioFileRef);
if(result) printf("ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL %ld \n", result);

AudioStreamBasicDescription clientFormat;
memset(&clientFormat, 0, sizeof(clientFormat));


result = AudioUnitGetProperty(ioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 0, & clientFormat, &size);
 if(result) printf("AudioUnitGetProperty %ld \n", result);

result = ExtAudioFileSetProperty(extAudioFileRef,kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat,sizeof(clientFormat),&clientFormat);
if(result) printf("ExtAudioFileSetProperty %ld \n", result);

result =  ExtAudioFileWriteAsync(extAudioFileRef, 0, NULL);
if (result) {[self printErrorMessage: @"ExtAudioFileWriteAsync error" withStatus: result];}

result = AudioUnitAddRenderNotify(ioUnit, renderCallback, (__bridge void*)self);
if (result) {[self printErrorMessage: @"AudioUnitAddRenderNotify" withStatus: result];}
}
```

// And finally, the rendercallback

```
static OSStatus renderCallback (void *                       inRefCon,
                            AudioUnitRenderActionFlags * ioActionFlags,
                            const AudioTimeStamp *       inTimeStamp,
                            UInt32                       inBusNumber,
                            UInt32                       inNumberFrames,
                            AudioBufferList *            ioData) 
{

OSStatus result;
if (*ioActionFlags == kAudioUnitRenderAction_PostRender){
    MusicPlayerController* THIS = (__bridge MusicPlayerController *)inRefCon;

       result =  ExtAudioFileWriteAsync(THIS->extAudioFileRef, inNumberFrames, ioData);
       if(result) printf("ExtAudioFileWriteAsync %ld \n", result); 

}
return noErr; 
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So I finally sorted this out! Ugh, what an information scavenger hunt.

Anyway, here is the bit in the docs for ExtAudioFile that I missed (see bolded text). I wasn't setting this property. Data was being written to my .m4a file but it was unreadable at playback. So to sum up: I have a bunch of AUSamplers -> AUMixer -> RemoteIO. A render callback on the RemoteIO instance writes the data out to disk in a compressed m4a format. So it is possible to generate compressed audio on the fly (iOS 5/iPad 2)

Seems pretty robust - I had some printf statements in the rendercallback and the write worked fine.

Yay!

> ExtAudioFileProperty_CodecManufacturer
>   The manufacturer of the codec to be used by the extended audio file object. Value is a read/write UInt32. **You must specify this property before setting the kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat (page 20) property, which in turn triggers the creation of the codec.** Use this property in iOS to choose between a hardware or software encoder, by specifying kAppleHardwareAudioCodecManufacturer or kAppleSoftwareAudioCodecManufacturer.
>   Available in Mac OS X v10.7 and later.
>   Declared in ExtendedAudioFile.h.

```
// specify codec
UInt32 codec = kAppleHardwareAudioCodecManufacturer;
size = sizeof(codec);
result = ExtAudioFileSetProperty(extAudioFileRef, 
                                 kExtAudioFileProperty_CodecManufacturer, 
                                 size, 
                                 &codec);

if(result) printf("ExtAudioFileSetProperty %ld \n", result);
```

Comment: Thanks so much man! I just got recording directly to AAC (m4a) working!

Comment: The only part where I got stuck was setting the kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat. It had to do with interleaving (The sound was audible but with lots of cracks). My audioFormat (format of input buffers) is interleaved and I needed to set the kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat to exactly audioFormat.

Comment: @skinnyTOD This worked. Thanks so much, But, every second or third time I call the startRecordingAAC function, I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error (code=1, address=0x2f8) error and the application quits. Any idea how I can sort this issue out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @BijoyThangaraj - I didn't encounter that. Maybe you are not retaining something (if you are not using ARC) or something is not being created. See if you can determine what is throwing the bad access error from the console log.

Comment: Remember to call `OSStatus result = ExtAudioFileDispose(extAudioFileRef);` when done with the recording, otherwise it will be a corrupted .m4a file

Comment: Thank you TOMATO and @k7k0. After struggling for a few days, I finally get it to worked. I followed TOMATO all the way through and the final bit was from k7k0.

Answer (score 1):

Did you write the magic cookie required at the start of an mpg 4 audio file?

You also need to do at least the first file write outside of the audio unit render callback.

Added:

Did you flush and close the audio file properly at the end?  (outside of the AU callback)

Comment: thanks for the reply. No, I didn't write the cookie - didn't know I had to. I've used the TPAACAudioConverter (https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPAACAudioConverter) and that works fine (though not real time) - and doesn't use a cookie. Confusing.

Comment: The documents for ExtAudioFileWriteAsync say you have to do one last thing after the end of recording.

Comment: Sorted it out - I wasn't specifying the codec manufacturer. Thanks for the nudge to look at the ExtAudio docs again. Will post the code as an answer

Answer (score 0):

It appears there's a little bit more to this than just specifying the Codec for the output audio file ID.

According to this thread: [ExtAudioFileWrite to m4a/aac failing on dual-core devices (ipad 2, iphone 4s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719865/extaudiofilewrite-to-m4a-aac-failing-on-dual-core-devices-ipad-2-iphone-4s) certain iPhone models (4S) for example, don't play nice with the hardware decoder.

From my experience with a 4S, trying to encode an AAC file with the hardware codec either a) works sometimes, b) fails with an error -66567 (kExtAudioFileError_MaxPacketSizeUnknown) or c) writes a few samples out and then just hangs with no traceable error.

The software codec works fine on an iPhone 4S at the expense of slower performance.

Edit: Some are claiming that the hardware codec doesn't like 44.1kHz sample rate. I have yet to confirm this.