# How to record/save audio being played in iPhone Application?

Tags: iphone, core-audio, audio-recording, audiounit

I wanted to record (save as a file in document directory) audio that is being played in the application. Basically can I hook to Audio output buffers and can read/save those buffers in the file?

I read some blogs and searched on a google. Most of them were pointing to the AudioUnit.

I have tried using AudioUnit - RemoteIO but I could not achieve what I wanted to, probably I messed something.

Following is the code that I have written for initializing the AudioUnit

```
OSStatus status;

// Describe audio component
AudioComponentDescription desc;
desc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
desc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;
desc.componentFlags = 0;
desc.componentFlagsMask = 0;
desc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;

// Get component
AudioComponent inputComponent = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &desc);

// Get audio units
status = AudioComponentInstanceNew(inputComponent, &mAudioUnit);

// Enable IO for recording
UInt32 flag = 1

// Enable IO for playback
status = AudioUnitSetProperty(mAudioUnit, 
                              kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, 
                              kAudioUnitScope_Output, 
                              kOutputBus,
                              &flag, 
                              sizeof(flag));

// Describe format
AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat={0};
audioFormat.mSampleRate         = kSampleRate;
audioFormat.mFormatID           = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
audioFormat.mFormatFlags        = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket    = 1;
audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame   = 1;
audioFormat.mBitsPerChannel     = 16;
audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket     = 2;
audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame      = 2;

// Apply format
status = AudioUnitSetProperty(mAudioUnit, 
                              kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, 
                              kAudioUnitScope_Output, 
                              kInputBus, 
                              &audioFormat, 
                              sizeof(audioFormat));


// Set input callback
AURenderCallbackStruct callbackStruct;
callbackStruct.inputProc = playbackCallback;
callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = self;

status = AudioUnitSetProperty(mAudioUnit, 
                              kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback, 
                              kAudioUnitScope_Input, 
                              kOutputBus,
                              &callbackStruct, 
                              sizeof(callbackStruct));
AudioUnitInitialize(mAudioUnit);
AudioOutputUnitStart(mAudioUnit);
```

And in the playbackCallback :

```
static OSStatus playbackCallback(void *inRefCon, 
                             AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags, 
                             const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp, 
                             UInt32 inBusNumber, 
                             UInt32 inNumberFrames, 
                             AudioBufferList *ioData) {    
double timeInSeconds = inTimeStamp->mSampleTime / kSampleRate;
printf("\nPLAYBACK %fs inBusNumber: %lu inNumberFrames: %lu ", timeInSeconds, inBusNumber, inNumberFrames);

AudioBufferList bufferList;

SInt16 samples[inNumberFrames]; // A large enough size to not have to worry about buffer overrun
memset (&samples, 0, sizeof (samples));

bufferList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
bufferList.mBuffers[0].mData = samples;
bufferList.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = 1;
bufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = inNumberFrames*sizeof(SInt16);

ViewController* THIS = THIS = (__bridge ViewController *)inRefCon;

OSStatus status;
status = AudioUnitRender(THIS->mAudioUnit,     
                         ioActionFlags, 
                         inTimeStamp, 
                         kOutputBus, 
                         inNumberFrames, 
                         &bufferList);

if (noErr != status) {

    printf("AudioUnitRender error: %ld", status); 
    return noErr;
}

// Now, we have the samples we just read sitting in buffers in bufferList
ExtAudioFileWriteAsync(THIS->mAudioFileRef, inNumberFrames, &bufferList);

return noErr;
}
```

Above mAudioFileRef is reference of the mp3 file that I have created in the `viewDidLoad`.

When I run above program, I am getting AudioUnitRender Error: -50. and mp3 file is not getting populated with the data.

Probably I have made some mistake in setting up the audio unit or in reading the buffer from ioData.

Any kind of help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using novocaine? https://github.com/alexbw/novocaine

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Many things could be going wrong here.

- I dont know how are you initialising your ExtAudioFileRef.
- What client format are you setting to it.
- What audio Format are you setting to it (yeah right mp3).
- What file format are you using.
- They all have to work together seamlessly.

Nevertheless, Have a look at this entry. It is a perfectly working sample code:

[Recording to AAC from RemoteIO: data is getting written but file unplayable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113977/recording-to-aac-from-remoteio-data-is-getting-written-but-file-unplayable)

And it kinda does what you need. Record compressed audio on the fly.

Have you initialise your `ExtAudioFileWriteAsync` like this(prior to the callback)?

```
ExtAudioFileWriteAsync(extAudioFileRefVar, 0, NULL);
```

It is really hard to tell what, out of all the possible things, could be going wrong, without more code.