# Compress audio upload to soundcloud

Tags: objective-c, upload, compression, soundcloud, aac

Our ios app records to wav, then that can be uploaded to Soundcloud. As recordings can be 5mins, thats 50 meg, so upload is slow. is there any Obj C code for ios that compresses eg to AAC or IM4 which we could use? Iphone 4 and up can do hardware/optimised audio compression apparently.

on the old SC API discussion, a coder called Steve discussed this and said he had got it to work, so looks like its possible.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/soundcloudapi/2TxziUEPDwA/idJHmXJKlj0J

thanks
Matt Black

Answer (score 1):

It is possible - see my question and later answer here: [Recording to AAC from RemoteIO: data is getting written but file unplayable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113977/recording-to-aac-from-remoteio-data-is-getting-written-but-file-unplayable).

I forget the filesize numbers right now but I recall they were pretty good. Performance was also good (on 2nd gen iPad).

I didn't do anything with uploading it to SoundCloud (would be interested know how that goes).